# sleep called from thread will never finish with large time

Tags: c++, multithreading, time, sleep, c++-chrono

I have a basic timer function, but it will only work when the sleeping period is fairly small. If DELAY is less than about 500ms, the function will work fine. I've tried other sleeping methods, including sleep(), usleep(), nanosleep(), and gettimeofday(), and they all stop working when the DELAY (adjusted for each function) is too large (generally stops working between 0.3 and 0.5 seconds). When it doesn't work, the sleeping function won't return anything, it will just never finish executing.

For example:

```
void executeTimer(MyObject *obj) {
    printf("Starting timer, delay = %d\n", DELAY);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(DELAY));
    printf("Complete\n");
    obj->doSomething();
}
```

called later in the program via:

```
timer = std::thread(executeTimer, this);
```

will never output "Complete" if DELAY is greater than about 400-500.

Does anyone know why this wouldn't be working? Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you waiting for the thread to finish by calling `join`?

Comment: @bamboon: I call timer.join() in the doSomething() method, after the 'timer' should have completed. I also call join() in the destructor if it is still timing.

Comment: can you please post a minimal compilable example.